# Using pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset with dataframe as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have an input pandas Dataframe with date and time in following format. I got this from a SQL server. I think it is the number of days from 1900/01/01

| date | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44084 | 44085.125002 | 44085.128478 |
| 44085 | 44086.125003 | 44086.128923 |
| 44086 | 44087.125008 | 44087.127888 |

I found that I can convert one of the values into datetime using the following code.

For Time fields,

```
pd.datetime(1900,1,1) + pd.DateOffset(seconds=round(44085.128478 * 24*60*60))
```

For Date fields,

```
pd.datetime(1900,1,1) + pd.DateOffset(44084)
```

How do I apply the same to a dataframe of offsets to produce something like this ?

| date | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-12 00:00:00 | 2020-09-13 03:00:00 | 2020-09-13 03:05:00 |
| 2020-09-13 00:00:00 | 2020-09-14 03:00:00 | 2020-09-14 03:05:39 |
| 2020-09-14 00:00:00 | 2020-09-15 03:00:01 | 2020-09-15 03:04:10 |

There might be an option to convert this when I use read_sql function itself. I tried parse_dates , it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `to_timedelta`:

```
df.apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')
```

Output:

```
        date                 start_time                   end_time
0 2020-09-12 2020-09-13 03:00:00.172800 2020-09-13 03:05:00.499200
1 2020-09-13 2020-09-14 03:00:00.259200 2020-09-14 03:05:38.947200
2 2020-09-14 2020-09-15 03:00:00.691200 2020-09-15 03:04:09.523200
```